# Django inline formsets and choicefields generate too many db queries

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I have a model with a number of foreign key fields, e.g. model Product with fields 'type', 'level', 'color', 'intensity' (just a generic example).

I then have a page to edit all products of a given type using a Type form with the products as an inline formset with the option to add additional products inline using `extra=10`.

The thing i find very strange is that each time when i output one of the foreign key choice fields on the template Django queries the database for the get the options (every time).

For example:

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.level }}
    {{ form.color }}
    {{ form.intensity }}
{% endfor %}
```

With 20 products (and 10 empty extra forms) the above code issues 30 `select * from ...` from level, color and intensity totaling 90 queries (revealed using the Django Debug Toolbar), where 3 should be sufficient. The options are unlikely to change mid request, but even if they did I definitely wouldn't want some newly added options to appear in the last 5 forms only.

***Is there any way to optimize my models/forms/views/templates so that the database doesn't get hammered like this unnecessarily?***

-

Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to django and python and can't help thinking there must be a way to address this built in somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
field_queryset = Test.objects.all()    
for form in formset:
        form.fields['test_field'].queryset = field_queryset
```

Like this.

Comment: Nice Denis, makes sense, just make them all use the same queryset object. Took you 11 months to chime in with an answer and I another 8 months to accept it. In the mean time addressed this by fully caching the 'type', 'level', 'color' types, on the premise that these are pretty much constants that won't change. But thanks, this is a simple approach that I will keep in mind next time.

Comment: This doesn't work. The forms will be constructed with the default querysets before you can replace them like this, so it'll do just as many queries.

Comment: @Adrián, actually "yes and no" I think. You are right, the default querysets will probably get created in the Form constructor. However, creating a queryset is not the same as querying the database. If you replace the queryset before the first queries are issued you can still save all the unnecessary calls to the database. You would need to replace these before displaying the first form in the template, and before calling `save` on each form.

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense but nope :( Apparently, (as I've been told on IRC), `ModelChoiceField` makes a clone of the queryset so a custom form field would be needed.

Comment: This doesn't work. The forms seem to call .all() on the queryset which creates a new one which doesn't share results with the original queryset and the other forms. (Django 1.7.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can [change the queryset used by the formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset), then you could use [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to generate the FK joins rather than to execute a query at each forloop iteration.

Comment: I don't see how these would help in this situation. The queryset is for selecting the products' current values, and select_related could help to fetch the level/color/intensity objects currently linked to each product. How does select_related actually help in prefetching the entire set of select options to populate the Select box?

Comment: Ok so you could either use an ajax autocomplete (django-ajax-selects) either use a query cache (johnnycache).

Comment: This helped me reduce the number of queries in my formset.