# Duplicate query for every form in the formset

Tags: python, django

In my django application I have users which can have multiple positions. ie: The Position model has a foreign key to the User model. By using a django `modelformset_factory` I output all the positions associated to the currently logged in user as follows:

Views.py:

```
class ABCUpdate(View):

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        PositionFormSet = modelformset_factory(Position)
        formset = PositionFormSet(queryset=user.position_set.all().prefetch_related('symbol'))
        return render(request,
                      'some_template.html',
                      {'formset': formset})
```

some_template.html

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% for position in formset %}
    <div class="row">
      {{ position }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit">
    Update
  </button>
</form>
```

Position model:

```
class Position(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    symbol = models.OneToOneField(Symbol)
    # more fields...
```

One of the fields on `some_template.html` is the `symbol` field (ie: the one for which I am using `prefetch_related` in the above snippets). `Symbol` is from a different model using a foreign key. This means that on the html template, the `symbol` field is a dropdown allowing the user to select the desired symbol.

This all works correctly, however the problem is that the database is being queried for every single form in the formset to retrieve the list of `symbol`'s. For example if the user has 10 positions, then each position will have a dropdown for symbol,...which results in a separate database query to retrieve all the symbols.

How do I go about just doing one query for all the available `symbol`'s and using that for the dropdown in every form in the formset?

Comment: A little bit unclear: Is there FK from `Position` to `Symbol` or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, the foreign key is from Position to Symbol. In other words, a user can have multiple positions. Then for each position they will select one symbol, which comes from the symbol table/model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django inline formsets and choicefields generate too many db queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583096/django-inline-formsets-and-choicefields-generate-too-many-db-queries)

Comment: I have added part of the Position model to the original post for clarity

Comment: @MuhammadTahir yes the post you mention is the same issue as im having. But if you read through that post and the comments, the solution does not work. I have also tried the solution, it does not work.

Comment: @darkpool you are right, taking my close vote back.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should point in prefetch_related all the fields of the model Position that have a link to another model, in your cases you must add field user:
`PositionFormSet(queryset=user.position_set.all().prefetch_related('symbol', 'user'))`.

---

P.S. it worked for me.